# Binding property of type Brush throws exception on asynchronous call

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, async-await, mvvm-light

I'm binding an observable Collection to a Data Grid.The collection fetched from server through an asynchronous call. The collection model contains a property called 'BackgroundBrush' of type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush' which is bind to background color of a template column in Data Grid. The brush property can be a SolidColorBrush or LinearGradientBrush depends on the business logic applied to that property.

While rendering data to Data Grid, the application throw an exception like this "Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject."

Things noticed while debugging issue

1. The issue is with 'Background' property. Commented out this property binding and making asynchronous call works fine.
2. Making the service call synchronous works fine, but i need this as an asynchronous one.
3. Make the service call in Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke doesn't make any difference

Below is the sample application code

Model

```cs
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public Brush BackgroundBrush { get; set; }
}
```

View Model

```cs
private ObservableCollection<Model> _dataCollection;

public ObservableCollection<Model> DataCollection
{
    get { return _dataCollection; }
    set
    {
        _dataCollection = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => DataCollection);
    }
}

public RelayCommand LoadCommand { get; private set; }

private async Task LoadData()
{
    var list = await Task.Run(() => GetData());
    DataCollection = new ObservableCollection<Model>(list);

}

private ObservableCollection<Model> GetData()
{
    return new ObservableCollection<Model>()
    {
        new Model()
        {
            Address = "a",
            Email = "2",
            Name = "3",
            BackgroundBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SaddleBrown)
        }
    };
}
```

View

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="{Binding BackgroundBrush}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Don't post your code as images. Use proper code blocks instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Media.Brush` is a `DependencyObject` and thus needs to be created on the `Dispatcher` thread.

`ObservableCollection` uses notifications to the UI via `INotifyCollectionChanged` to enable it's `Observer` pattern implementation which means it also needs to be constructed on the `Dispatcher` thread. You cannot load the contents of an `ObservableCollection` from another thread (i.e. asynchronously) without writing a custom implementation to raise the notifications on the correct thread.

**Edit:**

To solve your problem - create the `ObservableCollection` in the constructor and never overwrite the property reference from the other thread.

Write `LoadData()` and `GetData()` as follows:

```
    private async Task LoadData()
    {
        var list = await Task.Run(() => GetData());
        list.ForEach(item => Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
        {
           DataCollection.Add(item);
        }));

    }

    private List<Model> GetData()
    {
        var modelObject =
            new Model()
            {
                Address = "a",
                Email = "2",
                Name = "3",
            };
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
        { 
            modelObject.BackgroundBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SaddleBrown);
        });

       return new List<Model>(){ modelObject };
    }
```

Comment: its working ..Thanks toadflakz..One more case to consider in real world scenario. In my original solution the GetData() method is a business layer call and it's a different project (other than WPF project). In that case the Dispatcher doesn't work. Right?. So the only workaround is to  move that logical operation from business to view model and do it in main thread.Right?

Comment: You could easily move the `BackgroundBrush` set call to the `LoadData` method before calling `Add` for the item. Be careful of embedding presentation items like a `BackgroundBrush` into your `Model` - that way much pain and suffering lies... ;-)

Comment: Yes. I know. Actually the model was my business object  and I want to unit test that business logic that I applied to generate the background brush. Otherwise I will do it in a converter.

Answer (score 1):

That's because everything goes inside `await Task.Run` runs on a different thread. so you can't change the binding source `DataCollection` in it. Since `ObservableCollection` fires events to update the binding target and it won't allow changes from a different thread.

So your `GetData` function should return a normal collection:

```
private IEnumerable<Model> GetData()
{
    return new List<Model>()
    {
         new Model(){...}
    };
}
```

Another problem is the `Brush`. Your model (thread-safe) should use `Color` and your viewModel (bindable) should use `Brush`. So you should either add a Color property to your model which can be set in async call of GetData. Something like this:

```
private Color _color;
public Color Color 
{ 
    get{ return _color; } 
    set
    { 
        _color = value; 
        Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color)); 
    } 
}
public Brush Brush { get; set; }
```

Or you don't bind to Model and follow standard MVVM pattern.

For the parts which involve dependency properties or any binding source you need to invoke from dispatcher. e.g.

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => aThreadSafeFunction());
```

However in this case you can read the whole list first, then convert it to an ObservableCollection:

```
private async Task LoadData()
{
    //load thread-safe data asynchronously
    var list = await Task.Run(() => GetData());
    //set binding source in the same thread
    DataCollection = new ObservableCollection<Model>(list);
}
```

Comment: No luck. Throws the same exception "Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject."

Comment: Thanks. But the brush can be SolidColorBrush or LinearGradientBrush and it can't replace with a Color.Right?.
Actually the brush has been generated from a business logic with the help of model data. So I have to move that logical operation from business to view model and do it in main thread.Right?

Comment: There are many ways to make it thread-safe. in a slightly different implementation of GetData you can directly use a brush in model and load its value. But you have to **make sure** that specific set-brush-value operation is done within the same thread. i.e. a dispatcher from main thread should invoke that operation.

Comment: It seems that toadflakz has already said what I wanted to say!